Disable Inno Setup task by condition (on the first install)
I have got task:
[Tasks]
Name: "backup"; Description: "Do backup"; Flags: unchecked

I need checkbox of this task to be unable to tick ("grayed out"/disabled) in case of fresh installation (not upgrading the application)
In my .iss file i have got function which checks if it's an upgrade or fresh installation:
function CheckIsUpgrade: Boolean;

How to use that method to determine if "backup" task will be "grayed out"/disabled, or it will be enabled and user during installation will choose whether to do backup (tick checkbox) or not (leave checkbox unticked)

The easiest solution is to hide the checkbox altogether using Check parameter:
[Tasks]
Name: "backup"; Description: "Do backup"; Flags: unchecked; Check: CheckIsUpgrade

